# How to check if array contains item in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, iteration, javascript-objects

I have an *array* of **playlists**. A playlist *has many* **posts**.

I am trying to determine whether the **selected playlist** *already contains* the **post** I choose to add.

Currently, I'm getting *"Already added"* if *any playlist* in the **playlists** array contains that **post**.

**I only want to *add posts* to `playlists` that DO NOT already contain that *post*.**

Basically, I want to still be able to add a post to a playlist even if another playlist contains that post.

```
const confirmAdd = (selectedPlaylist, selectedPost) => {
    for(var i = 0; i < playlists.length; i++) {
        if (playlists[i].posts.length > 0) {
            if (playlists[i].posts.some(post => post.id != selectedPost.id)) {
                console.log("Success")
            } else {
                console.log("Already added")
            }
            break
        } else {
            console.log("Success")
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you exactly need from this?

Comment: Is it `playlist` or `playlists`?

Comment: What is the "*selected playlist*"? Your code treats all playlists the same.

Comment: in your `.some` method isn't `item` ? already a post ? if so it should be `.some(item => item.id !== post.id)`

Comment: I want to still be able to add a post to a playlist even if another playlist contains that post.

Comment: Just made some edits, hope that makes more sense now

Comment: Why are you evaluating all the playlists, when you are only concerned about the selected playlist?

Comment: terrymorse - Just replaced playlists[i] with selectedPlaylist, and it worked now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `playlist` parameter to the `confirmAdd()` function should be `playlists` since that is what you are using within the function

Answer (score 0):

you can use "indexOf"

```
let myArray = ["hello", "this", "is", "array"];

if(myArray.indexOf("hello") > -1){
     console.log("Hello is available")
}else{
     console.log("not available")

}
```

The indexOf() method returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string.

This method returns -1 if the value to search for never occurs.

-w3schools

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has a lot of great functions baked in to help with array manipulation.

For this task, you can use [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check an array for duplicate data.

```
if(playlist.includes(post)){
    ...do the thing
} else {
    ...do the other thing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I guess you have information about the selected playlist and if it's an object let's refer it by an object called `selectedPlaylist`. In that case your code should be something like below

```
function confirmAddFn(selectedPlaylist = {}, reqpost = {}) {

        //Here Selected Play list is the reference object of the selection

        //searching for the post
        let filteredPost = selectedPlaylist.posts.items.filter(post => post.id == reqpost.id);

        //if there is a post log already exsist
        if (filteredPost.length > 0) {
            console.log("Already Exsist");
        }
        else {
            //else add to the ref ob
            selectedPlaylist.posts.items.push(reqpost);
        }

    }
```

Now, in case you don't have the selected object and just have the index of the selected post. the below code should help

```
function confirmAddFn(playList = [], reqpost = {}, selectedPlayListIndex = -1) {

    //Here Selected Play list is the reference object of the selection
    let selectedPlaylist = playList[selectedPlayListIndex];

    //searching for the post
    let filteredPost = selectedPlaylist.posts.items.filter(post => post.id == reqpost.id);

    //if there is a post log already exsist
    if (filteredPost.length > 0) {
        console.log("Already Exsist");
    }
    else {
        //else add to the ref ob
        selectedPlaylist.posts.items.push(reqpost);
    }

}
```